# How to slice a 3D matrix in matlab getting an array

Tags: matlab

Consider having a 3D matrix in matlab where

```
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
A(:,:,2) = [11 22 33;44 55 66;77 88 99];
A(:,:,3) = [111 222 333;444 555 666;777 888 999];
```

Well when I ask for

```
A(1:end,1,:)
```

I get three different answers:

```
A(1:end,1,1) = [1 2 3];

A(1:end,1,2) = [11 22 33];

A(1:end,1,3) = [111 222 333];
```

I want to get this in one instruction possibly without cycles and so on:

```
[1 2 3;11 22 33;111 222 333]
```

How to get it?

I want a new matrix not a series of vectors.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
squeeze(A(1,:,:))'
```

works.  I think that if I were either smarter or willing to spend more time on this I could do it without a transpose, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Been searching for a solution to this problem for a while, not sure why squeeze() isn't getting more love.